# disabling multitouch not working ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a view controller(VC) having 3 buttons(country , state , city). On click of these buttons , i am presenting another VC(using popover segue) , which is a search table to search country (or  states or city). Now if user clicks two buttons , then both the view controller are presented at the same time. I want only one to be presented.How to do this?

Tried self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO; but not working.
code of the searchVC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIImage *bgApplication = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-app-568h.jpg"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgApplication];

    self.searchItems = [self loadData];
    self.filteredSearchItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.searchItems count]];

    for (UIView *view in self.SearchBarBase.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)view;
            tf.delegate = self;
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (NSArray *)loadData
{
    MatchDayDataController * sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    NSArray *data = [sharedController fetchStates];
    //NSLog(@"states: %@", data);

    return data;
}
```

Code of the presenter VC:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    keyboardIsShown = NO;

    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];

    // Load match venue data
    self.locationField.text = sharedController.matchVenue;

    //Load home team related data
    NSString *stateText = [sharedController.homeStateName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([stateText length] == 0 )
    {
        self.selectHomeAssoc.enabled = NO;
        self.selectHomeClub.enabled = NO;
    }
    NSString *homeAssocText = [sharedController.homeAssociationName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([homeAssocText length] == 0 )
    {
        self.selectHomeAssoc.enabled = YES;
        self.selectHomeClub.enabled = NO;
    }
    NSString *homeClubText = [self.homeClub.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([homeClubText length] == 0 )
    {
        self.selectHomeClub.enabled = YES;
    }

    self.stateTextFieldHome.text = sharedController.homeStateName;
    self.homeAssociation.text = sharedController.homeAssociationName;
    self.homeClub.text = sharedController.homeClubName;;
    self.homeTeam.text = sharedController.homeTeamName;

    // Away team related data
    self.stateTextFieldAway.text = sharedController.awayStateName;
    self.awayAssociation.text = sharedController.awayAssocationName;
    self.awayClub.text = sharedController.awayClubName;
    self.awayTeam.text = sharedController.awayTeamName;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];

    sharedController.matchVenue = self.locationField.text;

    // Save Venue related data
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateTimeString = [self.dateField.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];

    dateTimeString = [dateTimeString stringByAppendingString:self.timeField.text];
    //NSLog(@"DateTimeString : %@", dateTimeString);
    NSDate *matchDateTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
    sharedController.inspectionDate = matchDateTime;

    //Save Home team related data
    sharedController.homeTeamName = self.homeTeam.text;
    // Save away team related data
    sharedController.awayTeamName = self.awayTeam.text;
    [sharedController saveData];

    // hide the keyboard when we come back after leaving the cursor on text field.
    // I have called resignFirstResponder on homeTeam Text field. You can use any of text field to hide.
    [self.homeTeam resignFirstResponder];
    [self.awayTeam resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}


// This event is called when the user clicks on Done/Next button in the key board.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) {
        return true;
    }

    return [JLTValidator validateFields:@[self.locationField, self.dateField, self.timeField, self.homeTeam, self.homeClub, self.homeAssociation, self.stateTextFieldHome, self.stateTextFieldAway, self.awayAssociation, self.awayClub, self.awayTeam]];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"segue.identifier : %@", segue.identifier);
    self.popSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeStateFromButton"]
       || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeStateFromText"] )
    {
        SearchHomeStateViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeAssocFromButton"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeAssocFromText"])
    {
        HomeAssocSearchViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeClubFromButton"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchHomeClubFromText"])
    {
        SearchHomeClubViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayStateFromButton"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayStateFromText"])
    {
        StateViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayAssocFromButton"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayAssocFromText"])
    {
        SearchAwayAssocViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayClubFromButton"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSearchAwayClubFromText"])
    {
        SearchAwayClubViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = (id) self;
    }
}

-(void) searchHomeStateDone:(NSString *)selectedState
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.stateAwayTeam = sharedController.stateHomeTeam;
    sharedController.homeTeamName = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayStateName = sharedController.homeStateName;
    sharedController.awayAssocationName = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayAssociationId = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayClubName = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayClubId = EMPTY_STRING;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    self.selectHomeAssoc.enabled = YES;
    self.selectHomeClub.enabled = NO;
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) searchHomeAssocDone:(NSString *)selectedHomeAssoc
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.awayAssocationName = sharedController.homeAssociationName;
    sharedController.homeTeamName = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayStateName = sharedController.homeStateName;
    sharedController.awayAssociationId = sharedController.homeAssociationId;
    sharedController.awayClubName = EMPTY_STRING;
    sharedController.awayClubId = EMPTY_STRING;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    self.selectHomeClub.enabled = YES;
    [JLTValidator clearTextFieldValidation:self.homeAssociation];
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) searchHomeClubDone:(NSString *)selectedHomeClub
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.homeTeamName = EMPTY_STRING;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    [JLTValidator clearTextFieldValidation:self.homeClub];
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}

-(void) searchAwayStateDone:(NSString *)selectedAwayState
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.homeTeamName = self.homeTeam.text;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    [JLTValidator clearTextFieldValidation:self.stateTextFieldAway];
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) searchAwayAssocDone:(NSString *)selectedAwayAssoc
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.homeTeamName = self.homeTeam.text;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    [JLTValidator clearTextFieldValidation:_awayAssociation];
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) searchAwayClubDone:(NSString *) selectedAwayClub;
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
    sharedController.homeTeamName = self.homeTeam.text;

    [self updateDataOnScreen];
    [JLTValidator clearTextFieldValidation:_awayClub];
    [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) updateDataOnScreen
{
    MatchDayDataController *sharedController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];

   // sharedController.awayTeamName = EMPTY_STRING;

    self.stateTextFieldHome.text = sharedController.homeStateName;
    self.homeAssociation.text =sharedController.homeAssociationName;
    self.homeClub.text = sharedController.homeClubName;
    self.homeTeam.text = sharedController.homeTeamName;
    self.stateTextFieldAway.text = sharedController.awayStateName;
    self.awayAssociation.text = sharedController.awayAssocationName;
    self.awayClub.text = sharedController.awayClubName;
    //self.awayTeam.text = sharedController.awayTeamName;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please share some code that will help use to help you. :)

Comment: self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO should not working, cuz each button is a difference view.

Comment: Are your buttons available after touching? Or does the user have to actually hit two buttons simultaneously? Why is this even a problem? One thing you can try, is having one method handle all three buttons, and then set a flag when it is run. If this flag is set, the code will not be performed, so if the method is called twice, the code is only run once. You reset the flag when you return to the vc (i.e. in a protocol method called on the result view)

Comment: @OlegSobolev i have turned multiple touch disable on the VC that contains all the button. Will not it work even then?

Comment: You don't really need to use ONE method for all buttons, but I think the functionality is so similar that you don't really need three methods. Just check which button triggered the action (sender-property)

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create static bool variable `busy`, and at first line of each button action method check out state of this variable. If `busy` equal to `NO`, then set her to YES and at last line of action method or somewhere else set her to NO. If `busy` equal to `YES` do return from action method. So, until first called method didn't finish no other methods will be running.

```
@implementation yourController 

-(void)changeCountry
{
    if (!busy)
    {
        busy = YES;
        // do what you need
    } else return;
}

-(void)changeState
{
    if (!busy)
    {
        busy = YES;
        // do what you need
    } else return;
}

@end
```

You should implement singleton, which return a static instance with BOOL value for using him in difference viewControllers (1 mainC + 3 popOverC) and set `busy` to `NO` when you finish edition.

Comment: Agree with you, except that the 2nd button action will fire when 1st will be done (all in the same main thread). Also I propose to reset busy to NO via `[self performSelector:@selector(resetBusy) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];` with `-(void) resetBusy { busy = NO;}
` (this will be fire in the next loop of main thread)

Answer (score 0):

try `self.view.exclusiveTouch = YES;`

Comment: No, that would be a bad idea. From the docs: "By default, a view’s exclusiveTouch property is set to NO. If you set the property to YES, you mark the view so that, if it is tracking touches, it is the only view in the window that is tracking touches. Other views in the window cannot receive those touches."